# Deploy Yii2 advance template to a subdirectory

Tags: php, routes, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I was working on Yii2 project locally and it works fine, now on my domain I have the files on a subfolder so it will be domain.com/yiiproject . I'm using Yii2 advance template so I would like that when I type domain.com/yiiproject it will automatically show me the frontend project.

I've tried adding a baseUrl parameter in the settings but no luck, anyone knows how to do it with Yii2 advance template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy your entry index.php script into directory you want and make sure that `require` commands point to right folders/files. Sould work.

```
<?php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/common/config/main-local.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/config/main.php'),
require(__DIR__ . '/config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Comment: I tried this but now I'm getting a redirect loop. any ideas where this issue could be happening?

Comment: Got it working, my server didn't have install the mbstring extension, I installed it and all worked fine.

Comment: which index should I also use? the one on the back end or any other folder?

Answer (score 1):

make `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/yiiproject/
RewriteRule (.*) /yiiproject/$1
```